# MIT App Inventor Create a database that multiple devices can access

Tags: android, mysql, database

I would like to figure out how to create a database that multiple devices can access, this would be for a texting application.  I don't want to use phone numbers, or Bluetooth for this application though.  I already know how I can do that; however, I want to make a app that can connect 2+ other devices together and have a message center (I believe that there might be a way using WiFi connections.)

Comment: This is simply what web applications do. You have a central database, all clients (browsers or "apps" here) connect via network. The setup gets much more flexible if you add a server side scripting laybe between clients and the database.

Comment: Is there any way that you can show me how to do this?  I am actually taking this class in High School...  This isn't a homework project or anything, but my friends and I just want to figure out how to do it.

Comment: We certainly can answer to specific question. You are welcome. But if you ask about a general introduction into how to program networking communication and database usage, then I suggest you look for some of the millions of free "getting started" guides you will find all over the internet.

Comment: Look up the concept of 'three tier architecture'. In a nutshell: it's not really efficient, nor secure to let each client access the central database directly, introduce an application layer between them (this could be hosted on a webserver as a web application) and let this layer do the talking between the data store and the clients.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are looking for is the [TinyWebDB](http://www.appinventor.org/webDatabase). This component allows you to update/add or get data from a web database. By default it is set to the App Inventor database. This database is public and has limited storage, so your data will eventually be deleted. If you want to create your own web database for more privacy and so that your data doesn't get deleted follow the tutorial [here](https://appinventorapi.com/program-an-api-python/).
Sorry for the late answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can using firebase, console.firebase.com